# Problem deploying my project to maven repository since java.net moved from CollabNet to Project Kenai

Tags: java, maven, wagon

Problem deploying my jaudiotagger project since java.net moved from CollabNet to Project Kenai

I made the following changes to pom.xml

from

```
<repository><id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
```

to

```
<repository><id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
```

from

```
<repository>
<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
<id>java.net-maven2-repository</id>
<url>java-net:/maven2-repository/trunk/repository/</url>
</repository>
```

to

```
<repository>
<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
<id>java.net-m2-repository</id>
<url>java-net:/maven2-repository-svn/trunk/repository/</url>
</repository>
```

and Wagon version from

```
<version>1.8</version>
```

to

```
<version>1.12</version>
```

When I run mvn deploy it just complains:

Error retrieving previous build number for artifacts 'org:jaudiotagger:jar' repository metadata for: 'snapshot org:jaudiotagger:2.0.4-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: java.net-m2-repository due to an error: Connection failed:Unable to connect to https://svn.java.net/svn/maven2-repository-svn/trunk/repository

What am I doing wrong

thanks Paul

Comment: Is the prefix in the URL "java-net:" correct? Looks strange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have discontinued hosting their own repository but failed to mention it to anyone

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/forum-help/project-moved-project-kenjai-unable-deply-maven-repository?force=216